# My Qsort comparison function causes strange stuff in memory

Tags: c, pointers, qsort

To get used to dynamically creating two dimensional arrays, I wanted to create one that could be sorted by the fifth member in each array. The array is a multidimensional array of groups of doubles. Each group holds five doubles. The last two doubles are calculated based on the previous 3 by some random expression I wrote. There are as many arrays as there are groups of doubles it reads from a file. When I wrote it, I got very random results from the sort.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int getAllDoubles(char *, double ***); 
void printDouble(int, int, double **, char); 
int doubleCmp(const void *, const void *);  

int main(){
    double **arrayAll; 
    char *fileName = "doubles.dat"; 
    int doublesCount = getAllDoubles(fileName, &arrayAll); 


    printf("%d doubles successfully copied\n", doublesCount);
    printf("As a sample, here's #161\n"); 
    printDouble(161, doublesCount, arrayAll, 'a');

    double *tp = *(arrayAll + doublesCount-1) + 4; 
    printf("The last double is at %p and is %f\n", tp, *tp);
    printf("The first double * is at %p\n", &arrayAll[0]);  
    printDouble(1, doublesCount, arrayAll, 'f'); 
    printf("The first quaternary double is %f and it's at %p\n", arrayAll[0][4], &arrayAll[0][4]); 
    qsort(arrayAll, doublesCount, sizeof(double *), doubleCmp);

    int i; 
    for(i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        printDouble(i, doublesCount, arrayAll, 'f'); 
    } 
    return 0; 
}

int getAllDoubles(char *filename, double ***arrayAllPtr){
    FILE *fp; 
    int x, y, doublesCount = 0;
    double **arrayAll;  
    char c; 
    if((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
        return -1; 

    while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
        if(c == 'd')
            doublesCount++; 

    fclose(fp); 
    if((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
        return -1; 

    arrayAll = *arrayAllPtr = malloc(sizeof(double *) * doublesCount);
    for(y = 0; (getc(fp) == 'd') && y < doublesCount; y++){
            *(arrayAll+y) = malloc(sizeof(double) * 5); 
            if(fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf", *(arrayAll + y)+1, *(arrayAll+y)+2, *(arrayAll+y)) != 3)
                return -1;

            *(*(arrayAll+y)+3) = sqrt(*(*(arrayAll+y)) + *(*(arrayAll+y)+1));
            if(*(*(arrayAll + y)) == 0)
                    *(*(arrayAll+y)+4) = 0; 
            else
                *(*(arrayAll+y)+4) = (*(*(arrayAll+y)+1) / *(*(arrayAll+y)));

          while(getc(fp) != '\n')
            ;  
    }

    fclose(fp); 
    return doublesCount; 
}

void printDouble(int doubleNumber, int doublesCount, double **arrayAll, char option){
    if(doubleNumber <= 0 || doubleNumber >= doublesCount)
        puts("Invalid double!"); 
    else if(option == 'a'){
        printf("one: %f\ntwo: %f\nthree: %f\nfour: %f\nfive: %f\n",
        *(*(arrayAll+doubleNumber-1) + 0), *(*(arrayAll+doubleNumber-1) + 1),
        *(*(arrayAll+doubleNumber-1) + 2), *(*(arrayAll+doubleNumber-1) + 3),
        *(*(arrayAll+doubleNumber-1) + 4));
    }
    else if(option == 'f')
        printf("four: %f\n", *(*(arrayAll+doubleNumber-1)+4)); 
    return; 
}

int doubleCmp(const void *dOne, const void *dTwo){
    double *doubleOne, *doubleTwo; 
    doubleOne = (double *)dOne;
    doubleTwo = (double *)dTwo;
    printf("%p\n", doubleOne);
    printf("initial + 1 = %p\n", doubleOne + 1); 
    printf("initial + 2 = %p\n", doubleOne + 2);
    printf("initial + 3 = %p\n", doubleOne + 3);
    printf("initial + 4 = %p\n", doubleOne + 4);  
    printf("%f\n\n", *doubleOne);

    if((*doubleTwo) < (*doubleOne)){
        /*printf("%f comes before %f\n", *doubleOne, *doubleTwo);*/
        return -1; 
    }
    else if((*doubleTwo) > (*doubleOne)){
        /*printf("%f comes before %f\n", *doubleTwo, *doubleOne);*/  
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        /*printf("%p is equal to %p\n", *doubleOne, *doubleTwo); */
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

I threw in some printf statements (bad practice I know, but DDD will not let me proceed through my comparison function when it's called). Here's what I know:

(In this run) the address of the first double in the first group (and associatively, the first group of doubles)  is 0x2041250. The address of the fifth double (the one I'm looking to sort the array by) in the first group is 0x2042310. Shocking, because that's quite an increase in address for something that should only be 32 bytes away.

Normally that would convince me that maybe the method that populates the dynamic array needs to be fixed, but I can print every single group of doubles using a print function just fine.

What's even weirder are the printf statements inside the comparison function. Qsort starts with the first double * in my 2D array and it has the same value as the address of the first double. That's all well and good, but when I wrote printf statements to see what they do address arithmetic wise, the program yielded

(initial refers to the initial address, 0x2041250)
initial + 1 = 0x2041258 //Fine
initial + 2 = 0x2041260 //What
initial + 3 = 0x2041268 //Excuse me?
initial + 4 = 0x2041270 //;_;

And then to top it off, dereferencing the pointer, passed in as a void pointer but casted as double *, (expectedly) yields 0.000000.

I can't begin to understand what's happening here. Any ideas?

Comment: What gave you the idea that `printf()` statements are a bad debugging technique?  They can be extremely effective.

Comment: Your code is almost unreadable, in large part because you don't use array subscript notation.  For example: `*(*(arrayAll+y)+3) = sqrt(*(*(arrayAll+y)) + *(*(arrayAll+y)+1));` instead of `arrayAll[y][3] = sqrt(arrayAll[y][0] + arrayAll[y][1]);` is tantamount to an abuse of C. It would be extremely helpful to have a sample of the input data. It appears that each line should start with a `d` and then contain 3 double values. It also appears that you expect there to be more than 161 entries in the file since you 'sample' row 161. That's a very large number for getting the code to work; use 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rather heavily modified version of your code.  I've revised the input code to read a line at a time during the main input (the line counting loop I didn't fix; I would get rid of it, in fact, and count as I went).  I use the `rewind()` function to save closing and reopening the file.  I revise the code so it uses subscript notation for clarity.  I generated random data in the format XX.YY, so the print formats are `%6.2f` to accommodate that.

The crucial change is in the `doubleCmp()` function.  The values passed to it by `qsort()` are pointer to 'array of 5 `double`' (or pointer to pointer to `double`).  This fixes most of the problems; a lot of the rest of the code is idiosyncratic or eccentric but workable.

The code includes my diagnostic printing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int getAllDoubles(char *, double ***);
void printDouble(int, int, double **, char);
int doubleCmp(const void *, const void *);

int main(void)
{
    double **arrayAll;
    char *fileName = "doubles.dat";
    int doublesCount = getAllDoubles(fileName, &arrayAll);

    printf("%d doubles successfully copied\n", doublesCount);
    if (doublesCount <= 0)
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < doublesCount; i++)
        printDouble(i, doublesCount, arrayAll, 'a');

    double *tp = &arrayAll[doublesCount-1][4];
    printf("The last double is at %p and is %6.2f\n", tp, *tp);
    printf("The first double * is at %p\n", &arrayAll[0]);
    printDouble(1, doublesCount, arrayAll, 'f');
    printf("The first quaternary double is %6.2f and it's at %p\n", arrayAll[0][4], &arrayAll[0][4]);

    qsort(arrayAll, doublesCount, sizeof(double *), doubleCmp);

    for (int i = 0; i < doublesCount; i++)
        printDouble(i, doublesCount, arrayAll, 'a');

    return 0;
}

int getAllDoubles(char *filename, double ***arrayAllPtr)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int doublesCount = 0;
    double * *arrayAll;
    char c;
    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
        return -1;

    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == 'd')
            doublesCount++;
    }

    rewind(fp);

    arrayAll = *arrayAllPtr = malloc(sizeof(double *) * doublesCount);
    if (arrayAll == 0)
        return -1;

    char line[1024];
    for (int y = 0; y < doublesCount && fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0; y++)
    {
        arrayAll[y] = malloc(sizeof(double) * 5);
        if (arrayAll[y] == 0)
            return -1;  // Leak
        if (sscanf(line, "d %lf %lf %lf", &arrayAll[y][1], &arrayAll[y][2], &arrayAll[y][0]) != 3)
            return -1;  // Leak

        arrayAll[y][3] = sqrt(arrayAll[y][0] + arrayAll[y][1]);
        if (arrayAll[y][0] == 0)
            arrayAll[y][4] = 0;
        else
            arrayAll[y][4] = arrayAll[y][1] / arrayAll[y][0];
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return doublesCount;
}

void printDouble(int doubleNumber, int doublesCount, double **arrayAll, char option)
{
    if (doubleNumber < 0 || doubleNumber >= doublesCount)
        puts("Invalid double!");
    else if (option == 'a')
    {
        printf("%2d:  %6.2f:   %6.2f: %6.2f:  %6.2f:  %6.2f\n", doubleNumber+1,
               arrayAll[doubleNumber][0], arrayAll[doubleNumber][1],
               arrayAll[doubleNumber][2], arrayAll[doubleNumber][3],
               arrayAll[doubleNumber][4]);
    }
    else if (option == 'f')
        printf("four: %6.2f\n", arrayAll[doubleNumber][4]);
}

int doubleCmp(const void *dOne, const void *dTwo)
{
    double * const *d1 = dOne;
    double * const *d2 = dTwo;
    double const *doubleOne = *d1;
    double const *doubleTwo = *d2;
    printf("d1: ");
    printf("[0] = %6.2f; ", doubleOne[0]);
    printf("[1] = %6.2f; ", doubleOne[1]);
    printf("[2] = %6.2f; ", doubleOne[2]);
    printf("[3] = %6.2f; ", doubleOne[3]);
    printf("[4] = %6.2f\n", doubleOne[4]);
    printf("d2: ");
    printf("[0] = %6.2f; ", doubleTwo[0]);
    printf("[1] = %6.2f; ", doubleTwo[1]);
    printf("[2] = %6.2f; ", doubleTwo[2]);
    printf("[3] = %6.2f; ", doubleTwo[3]);
    printf("[4] = %6.2f\n", doubleTwo[4]);

    if (doubleTwo[0] < doubleOne[0])
    {
        /*printf("%f comes before %f\n", *doubleOne, *doubleTwo);*/
        return -1;
    }
    else if (doubleTwo[0] > doubleOne[0])
    {
        /*printf("%f comes before %f\n", *doubleTwo, *doubleOne);*/
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        /*printf("%p is equal to %p\n", *doubleOne, *doubleTwo); */
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Given this sample data set:

```
d  6.81 28.48  7.66
d 91.05 54.31 73.96
d 82.08 74.93 87.39
d 80.08 47.27  3.34
d 84.93 61.37 91.59
d 43.38 78.85 22.71
d 95.65 41.39 13.98
d 19.24  4.89 10.38
d  3.99 79.47 12.93
d 30.10  6.41 82.50
```

the output I got from a run of the program was:

```
10 doubles successfully copied
 1:    7.66:     6.81:  28.48:    3.80:    0.89
 2:   73.96:    91.05:  54.31:   12.85:    1.23
 3:   87.39:    82.08:  74.93:   13.02:    0.94
 4:    3.34:    80.08:  47.27:    9.13:   23.98
 5:   91.59:    84.93:  61.37:   13.29:    0.93
 6:   22.71:    43.38:  78.85:    8.13:    1.91
 7:   13.98:    95.65:  41.39:   10.47:    6.84
 8:   10.38:    19.24:   4.89:    5.44:    1.85
 9:   12.93:     3.99:  79.47:    4.11:    0.31
10:   82.50:    30.10:   6.41:   10.61:    0.36
The last double is at 0x7fc86b403e50 and is   0.36
The first double * is at 0x7fc86b403a20
four:   1.23
The first quaternary double is   0.89 and it's at 0x7fc86b403a90
d1: [0] =   7.66; [1] =   6.81; [2] =  28.48; [3] =   3.80; [4] =   0.89
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d2: [0] =  82.50; [1] =  30.10; [2] =   6.41; [3] =  10.61; [4] =   0.36
d1: [0] =  73.96; [1] =  91.05; [2] =  54.31; [3] =  12.85; [4] =   1.23
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =  87.39; [1] =  82.08; [2] =  74.93; [3] =  13.02; [4] =   0.94
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =   3.34; [1] =  80.08; [2] =  47.27; [3] =   9.13; [4] =  23.98
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =  82.50; [1] =  30.10; [2] =   6.41; [3] =  10.61; [4] =   0.36
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =  91.59; [1] =  84.93; [2] =  61.37; [3] =  13.29; [4] =   0.93
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =   7.66; [1] =   6.81; [2] =  28.48; [3] =   3.80; [4] =   0.89
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =  12.93; [1] =   3.99; [2] =  79.47; [3] =   4.11; [4] =   0.31
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =  10.38; [1] =  19.24; [2] =   4.89; [3] =   5.44; [4] =   1.85
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =  13.98; [1] =  95.65; [2] =  41.39; [3] =  10.47; [4] =   6.84
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =   7.66; [1] =   6.81; [2] =  28.48; [3] =   3.80; [4] =   0.89
d2: [0] =  22.71; [1] =  43.38; [2] =  78.85; [3] =   8.13; [4] =   1.91
d1: [0] =  91.59; [1] =  84.93; [2] =  61.37; [3] =  13.29; [4] =   0.93
d2: [0] =  73.96; [1] =  91.05; [2] =  54.31; [3] =  12.85; [4] =   1.23
d1: [0] =  73.96; [1] =  91.05; [2] =  54.31; [3] =  12.85; [4] =   1.23
d2: [0] =  87.39; [1] =  82.08; [2] =  74.93; [3] =  13.02; [4] =   0.94
d1: [0] =  91.59; [1] =  84.93; [2] =  61.37; [3] =  13.29; [4] =   0.93
d2: [0] =  87.39; [1] =  82.08; [2] =  74.93; [3] =  13.02; [4] =   0.94
d1: [0] =  73.96; [1] =  91.05; [2] =  54.31; [3] =  12.85; [4] =   1.23
d2: [0] =  82.50; [1] =  30.10; [2] =   6.41; [3] =  10.61; [4] =   0.36
d1: [0] =  87.39; [1] =  82.08; [2] =  74.93; [3] =  13.02; [4] =   0.94
d2: [0] =  82.50; [1] =  30.10; [2] =   6.41; [3] =  10.61; [4] =   0.36
d1: [0] =   7.66; [1] =   6.81; [2] =  28.48; [3] =   3.80; [4] =   0.89
d2: [0] =  13.98; [1] =  95.65; [2] =  41.39; [3] =  10.47; [4] =   6.84
d1: [0] =   7.66; [1] =   6.81; [2] =  28.48; [3] =   3.80; [4] =   0.89
d2: [0] =  10.38; [1] =  19.24; [2] =   4.89; [3] =   5.44; [4] =   1.85
d1: [0] =  13.98; [1] =  95.65; [2] =  41.39; [3] =  10.47; [4] =   6.84
d2: [0] =  10.38; [1] =  19.24; [2] =   4.89; [3] =   5.44; [4] =   1.85
d1: [0] =   7.66; [1] =   6.81; [2] =  28.48; [3] =   3.80; [4] =   0.89
d2: [0] =  12.93; [1] =   3.99; [2] =  79.47; [3] =   4.11; [4] =   0.31
d1: [0] =  10.38; [1] =  19.24; [2] =   4.89; [3] =   5.44; [4] =   1.85
d2: [0] =  12.93; [1] =   3.99; [2] =  79.47; [3] =   4.11; [4] =   0.31
d1: [0] =  13.98; [1] =  95.65; [2] =  41.39; [3] =  10.47; [4] =   6.84
d2: [0] =  12.93; [1] =   3.99; [2] =  79.47; [3] =   4.11; [4] =   0.31
d1: [0] =   7.66; [1] =   6.81; [2] =  28.48; [3] =   3.80; [4] =   0.89
d2: [0] =   3.34; [1] =  80.08; [2] =  47.27; [3] =   9.13; [4] =  23.98
 1:   91.59:    84.93:  61.37:   13.29:    0.93
 2:   87.39:    82.08:  74.93:   13.02:    0.94
 3:   82.50:    30.10:   6.41:   10.61:    0.36
 4:   73.96:    91.05:  54.31:   12.85:    1.23
 5:   22.71:    43.38:  78.85:    8.13:    1.91
 6:   13.98:    95.65:  41.39:   10.47:    6.84
 7:   12.93:     3.99:  79.47:    4.11:    0.31
 8:   10.38:    19.24:   4.89:    5.44:    1.85
 9:    7.66:     6.81:  28.48:    3.80:    0.89
10:    3.34:    80.08:  47.27:    9.13:   23.98
```

You can see from the diagnostics in `doubleCmp()` that it is able to print out the rows of data it is supposed to compare.  The output data is in the correct (descending) order in column 1.

---

#### Why the change in `doubleCmp()`?

> After just adding the change at the top in DoubleCmp, it started working, though I can't really figure out why.

The first dozen or so times you do this, it is tricky to think about.  After that, it gets easier and more or less automatic.

Let's consider a simpler sorting example:

```
int array[] = { 3, 9, 12,  1, 36, -2, 0 };
enum { ARRAY_SIZE = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) };

qsort(array, ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(array[0]), int_compare);
```

Now, we know that the signature of `int_compare()` must be:

```
int int_compare(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
   ...
}
```

but what are those void pointers pointing at?  The answer is that they point to an element of the array, and it is an array of integers, so the underlying type is `int *`.

```
int int_compare(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
   int const *ip1 = v1;
   int const *ip2 = v2;
   if (*ip1 < *ip2)
       return -1;
   else if (*ip1 > *ip2)
       return +1;
   else
       return 0; 
}
```

Or, since we're dealing with simple values, we could use:

```
int int_compare(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
   int i1 = *(int *)v1;
   int i2 = *(int *)v2;
   if (i1 < i2)
       return -1;
   else if (i1 > i2)
       return +1;
   else
       return 0; 
}
```

There are a couple of advantages to this organization for the comparator.  The first is that it works correctly regardless of the values in the array.  Sometimes, you'll see people suggesting a short cut such as `return i1 - i2;`, but this runs into problems with arithmetic overflow if the values in the array are big enough; the code shown works correctly regardless of the values in the array.  The second is that it generalizes fairly easily.  If this was comparing elements of an array of structures, you could add extra criteria when the first two compared fields are the same:

```
int int_compare(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
   struct dohickey const *ip1 = v1;
   struct dohickey const *ip2 = v2;
   if (ip1->member1 < ip2->member1)
       return -1;
   else if (ip1->member1 > ip2->member1)
       return +1;
   else if (ip1->member2 < ip2->member2)
       return -1;
   else if (ip1->member2 > ip2->member2)
       return +1;
   else
       return 0; 
}
```

Rinse and repeat for as many fields as are used to distinguish two values in the array.

Coming back to your problem, what you're passing to `qsort()` is an array of 'pointers to `double`', where each pointer to `double` points to the start of an array of 5 `double` values.

When the sort was processing an 'array of `int`', the comparator received two 'pointer to `int`' values.  When the sort is processing an 'array of pointer to `double`', the comparator receives two 'pointer to pointer to `double`'.  Generally, when the sort is processing an 'array of *type X*', the comparator receives two 'pointer to *type X*' values.

At the risk of confusing you, I'll also mention that what you have is not a 'true 2-dimensional array'.  That is declared using:

```
double array_2d[NROWS][NCOLS];
```

You'd sort that by calling:

```
qsort(array_2d, NROWS, sizeof(array_2d[0]), array_2d_cmp);
```

with:

```
int array_2d_cmp(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
    double (*a1)[NCOLS] = (double (*)[NCOLS])v1; // Cast away const cares
    double (*a2)[NCOLS] = (double (*)[NCOLS])v2; // Cast away const cares

    for (int i = 0; i < NCOLS)
    {
        if ((*a1)[i] < (*a2)[i])
            return -1;
        else if ((*a1)[i] > (*a2)[i])
            return +1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Demonstration of `qsort()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum { NROWS = 5, NCOLS = 7 };

static void dump_int_array_1d(char const *tag, size_t n, int a[n])
{
    printf("%-8s", tag);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf(" %3d", a[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}

static void dump_double_array_2d(char const *tag, char const *fmt, size_t rows, size_t cols, double a[rows][cols])
{
    printf("%s: (%zdx%zd)\n", tag, rows, cols);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf(fmt, a[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

static int array_2d_cmp(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
    double (*a1)[NCOLS] = (double (*)[NCOLS])v1;
    double (*a2)[NCOLS] = (double (*)[NCOLS])v2;
    //double const (* const a1)[NCOLS] = v1;
    //double const (* const a2)[NCOLS] = v2;
    //typedef double (*DoubleArray)[NCOLS];
    //DoubleArray const a1 = v1;
    //DoubleArray const a2 = v2;

    for (int i = 0; i < NCOLS; i++)
    {
        if ((*a1)[i] < (*a2)[i])
            return -1;
        else if ((*a1)[i] > (*a2)[i])
            return +1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void sort_2d_array_double(void)
{
    double array_2d[NROWS][NCOLS];

    for (int row = 0; row < NROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < NCOLS; col++)
        {
            int value = rand() % 10000;
            array_2d[row][col] = value / 100.0;
        }
    }
    /* Ensure there are some duplicates */
    array_2d[3][0] = array_2d[1][0];
    array_2d[4][0] = array_2d[0][0];
    array_2d[4][1] = array_2d[0][1];

    dump_double_array_2d("Before", "%6.2f", NROWS, NCOLS, array_2d);
    qsort(array_2d, NROWS, sizeof(array_2d[0]), array_2d_cmp);
    dump_double_array_2d("After", "%6.2f", NROWS, NCOLS, array_2d);
}

typedef int (*Comparator)(void const *v1, void const *v2);

static void sort_1d_array_int(Comparator comp_func)
{
    int array[] = { 3, 9, 12,  1, 36, -2, 0 };
    enum { ARRAY_SIZE = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) };

    dump_int_array_1d("Before:", ARRAY_SIZE, array);
    qsort(array, ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(array[0]), comp_func);
    dump_int_array_1d("After:", ARRAY_SIZE, array);
}

static int int_compare1(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
    int const *ip1 = v1;
    int const *ip2 = v2;
    if (*ip1 < *ip2)
        return -1;
    else if (*ip1 > *ip2)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}

static int int_compare2(void const *v1, void const *v2)
{
    int i1 = *(int *)v1;
    int i2 = *(int *)v2;
    if (i1 < i2)
        return -1;
    else if (i1 > i2)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    sort_2d_array_double();
    sort_1d_array_int(int_compare1);
    sort_1d_array_int(int_compare2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. After just adding the change at the top in DoubleCmp, it started working, though I can't really figure out why. The rest of your suggestions I'll be working in too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this for loop will only be executed if the first character in the file is `'d'` and then it will quit if the following character is different from `'d'`

```
for(y = 0; (getc(fp) == 'd') && y < doublesCount; y++){
        *(arrayAll+y) = malloc(sizeof(double) * 5); 
        if(fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf", *(arrayAll + y)+1, *(arrayAll+y)+2, *(arrayAll+y)) != 3)
            return -1;

        *(*(arrayAll+y)+3) = sqrt(*(*(arrayAll+y)) + *(*(arrayAll+y)+1));
        if(*(*(arrayAll + y)) == 0)
                *(*(arrayAll+y)+4) = 0; 
        else
            *(*(arrayAll+y)+4) = (*(*(arrayAll+y)+1) / *(*(arrayAll+y)));

      while(getc(fp) != '\n')
        ;  
}
```