# qsort on dynamic array of dynamic structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, qsort, pointer-to-pointer

I have the following struct

```
struct FOO {
    int x;
    double y;
}
```

and the array

```
FOO **manyfoos;
manyfoos = malloc( 10 * sizeof(FOO *) );
```

After this `manyfoos` is filled with dynamically allocated `FOO *` elements

```
manyfoos[i] = malloc( sizeof(FOO) );
manyfoos[i]->x = x;
manyfoos[i]->y = y;
```

I now want to sort `manyfoos` with `qsort()` and the following compare function

```
int foocmp(const void * p, const void * q) {
    const FOO * pp = (const FOO *)p;
    const FOO * qq = (const FOO *)q;

    return qq->x - pp->x;
}
```

Unfortunately the following command is giving unexpected results (`qq->x` and `pp->x` are random weird numbers).

```
qsort(manyfoos, 10, sizeof(FOO *), foocmp);
```

How can I make this work as expected?

Comment: Your comparator is given `const void *` values that are 'really' `const FOO **` values, not `const FOO *` values.  If you sort an array of `int`, the comparator is given `int *` (cast to `const void *`).  You're sorting an array of `FOO *`; therefore, you are given `const FOO **` values cast to `const void *`.

Comment: See also [My qsort comparison function causes strange stuff in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468561/15168).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your comparison-function is off.

The arguments it gets are pointers to the elements in the array `qsort()` tries to sort, so pointers to `FOO*`.

The fixed comparison-function is:

```
int foocmp(const void * p, const void * q) {
    const FOO* const * pp = p;
    const FOO* const * qq = q;

    return (*qq)->x - (*pp)->x; // Beware of overflow / underflow
}
```

I also left out the superfluous casts.

As an aside, avoid `sizeof(TYPE)`. Use `sizeof expr` instead, so you don't repeat the type scattered all over your code.